# Repeat value in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to repeat an item n times (where n is given from another column).

Presto contains repeat function https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html, but it's not supported by Athena. So, is there another way to repeat items?

For example (X, 3) -> [X, X, X].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this function isn't supported by Athena, because at this moment Athena uses Presto version 0.172 and this version of Presto doesn't have implemented mentioned function. I think that you will not find an alternative function, you can only use a workaround like this:

```
transform(sequence(1, 3), x-> 'X')
```

Comment: Athena version 2, [released](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference.html) in Nov 2020, does have this functionality since it is now using Presto 0.217. I just tested that I was able to run the `repeat(element, count)` function just fine.